# Mock a Perl module having multiple packages

Tags: perl, unit-testing, mocking, package, perl-module

I have the following scenario where I need to mock the subroutines in a module which has multiple packages.

My Module(moddemo.pm)

```
package A;

sub helloa
{
  print "Hello, Im in demomod module of package A\n";
  return 1;
}

package B;

sub hellob
{
 print "Hello, Im in demomod module of package B\n";
 return 1;
}

1;
```

I need to mock A::helloa(), B::hellob()  subroutines. Here is the code I have tried, but failed.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Test::MockModule;
use moddemo;

{
 my $mockobj = new Test::MockModule('moddemo');
 $mockobj->mock('A::helloa', sub { print "This is mocked object calling helloa function\n"; });
 $mockobj->mock('B::hellob', sub { print "This is mocked object calling hellob function\n";});
 modobj::A::helloa();
 modobj::B::hellob();
}
```

Any help how to mock these subroutines? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done it by redefining the subroutine.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Demo;

A::helloa();
{
    no warnings 'redefine';
    local *A::helloa = sub {
        print "helloa has changed\n";
        return 1;
    };
    A::helloa();
}
A::helloa();
```

Notes:

- The redefinition will cause a warning, so the `no warnings` line is needed to get rid of that.
- The redefinition is applied locally, so you should see that only the subroutine call within the block has changed.

Comment: Many thanks. This worked Great!! But is this method suggested over mocking when module has more than one package?

Comment: I did it this way because doing it with Test::MockModule wouldn't work with packages that are named differently to the .pm file. I suppose you could consider it a more manual way of doing it. Another module that would be more suitable for you in this situation is https://metacpan.org/pod/Sub::Override.

Answer (score 0):

I can be wrong but from what I see in the [module source](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/SIMONFLK/Test-MockModule-0.05/lib/Test/MockModule.pm) it seems impossible to use it in the way you try. MockModule first `require`s the needed package (`.pm` file) and then allows only subroutines from that package, i.e. no `::` in names are allowed.

As I understand it can be used in this way for testing modules (modified your code to fit its expectations):

`moddemo.pm`:

```
package moddemo;
use strict;
use warnings;

sub helloa
{
        print "moddemo::helloa\n";
        return 1;
}

sub hellob
{
        print "moddemo::hellob\n";
        return 1;
}

1;
```

Now the test file, `test.pl`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Test::MockModule;
use moddemo;

{
        my $mockobj = new Test::MockModule('moddemo');
        $mockobj->mock('helloa', sub { print "This is mocked object calling helloa function\n"; });
        $mockobj->mock('hellob', sub { print "This is mocked object calling hellob function\n";});

        # mocked versions
        moddemo::helloa();
        moddemo::hellob();
}

# now original versions
moddemo::helloa();
moddemo::hellob();
```

And finally the output, as expected:

```
This is mocked object calling helloa function
This is mocked object calling hellob function
moddemo::helloa
moddemo::hellob
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes I tried this before and it worked perfectly. But the problem is when the module has multiple packages. Is there any Perl module other than Test::MockModule, fit my expectation?

Comment: Not aware of any CPAN module for that (of course it may exist but I cannot name one), but you can at least look at Test::MockModule implementation (the place where it saves the original subroutine implementation in `sub mock`, and the code that replaces the code in `sub _replace_sub`) and create the mock object manually using the same typeglob technique. Typeglobs (`*name`) are described in `perlmod(1)`.